# How to compute propagation delay of satellite

Tags: delay, satellite

[image]

In the table propagation delays of different satellite system are given. I want to reproduce the data of this table.

According to my understanding, propagation delay is
$$\tau =\frac{D}{V}, $$
where \$D\$ is altitude, \$V\$ is speed of satellite.

For example, GEO: distance is 36000 km, speed is about 3 km/h.

$$\tau =\frac{36000}{3} = 12000 h  = 12000*3600  = 43200000000 ms$$

So, my calculation is wrong.

Is my equation wrong or my assumption?

Comment: You're using the wrong *speed*. Propagation delay has little to do with the speed of the satellite, and mostly to do with the speed of the information you're sending to it.

Comment: You need to use the propagation velocity of the RF link signal (the speed of light in this case), not the velocity of the satellite.

Comment: Satellite orbital speed is irrelevant here. The tiny radial movement << vast distance to the satellite.

Comment: Note also that table is for a satellite that is directly overhead, so range to the satellite = altitude.  This is a good approximation for a GEO satellite, but may not be for a satellite in LEO, where the slant range may be a lot further than the altitude.

Comment: @winny - That should orbital speed, or rev speed, not rotational speed.

Comment: @SteveSh Thanks! I was missing the English word for it. Peripheral speed was what I was looking for.

Comment: @winny - Here's a easy way I use to remember that difference.  The Earth revolves (or orbits) around the sun, and rotates on its axis.

Comment: @SteveSh Brilliant!

Comment: Where does 3 km/h come from?

Comment: @glen, I know. But it looks like the OP thinks that a geostationary satellite has a velocity of 3 km/h when a point on the equator has a speed of ~1500 km/h. I'm just teasing out the thought process.

Comment: @Andyaka Done! Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The speed of light through air and through space is 300,000 km per second therefore, for an object that is 36,000 km above earth, it will take \$\frac{36,000}{300,000}\$ seconds to receive a transmission from an earth-based station. That's 120 ms. Therefore, the total delay to **another** earth-based station (assuming instant reply processing by the satellite) will be 240 ms.